# Hi. I have a program with two .cpp files and one .hpp header file. Both the main.cpp and Log.cpp file give different errors on compiling using g++

Tags: c++

1. main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "log.hpp"

int main()
{
    InitLog();
    Log("Hello World");
    std::cin.get();
}
```

2. Log.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "log.hpp"

void InitLog()
{
    Log("Initialize Log");
}

void Log(const char *message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

3. log.hpp

```
#pragma once

void Log(const char *message);
void InitLog();
```

The errors are:

1. Log.cpp -
   undefined
   reference to `WinMain'
   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
2. main.cpp -
   c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\91813\AppData\Local\Temp\cckelbDG.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `InitLog()' c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\91813\AppData\Local\Temp\cckelbDG.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to` Log(char const*)'
   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You have two very different problems, actually. The first is that your project is set up as a native Windows project, not a console project. The second problem is that you don't build with both source files. Please [edit] your question to include your project settings and configuration, as well as telling us the environment you use to configure and build your project, and how you build your project.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.